Create Image from bytes results in ValueError: not enough image data
I am downloading images from an offline system (Google Photos)  I can download the files and save them locally that works fine.
However what i am trying to do is download them and turn them into a PIL Image so that i can use them and not have to store them locally first.
Works fine to save a file
    for media_item in media_items:
        image_data_response = authed_session.get(media_item['baseUrl'] + "=w500-h250")
        print(image_data_response)
        with open(media_item['filename'], "wb") as my_file:
            my_file.write(image_data_response.content)
        print(media_item['id'], media_item['filename'])

attempt to create PIL Image
for media_item in media_items:
        width = media_item['mediaMetadata']['width']
        height = media_item['mediaMetadata']['height']
        image_size = (500, 250)  # Width, height
        image_data_response = authed_session.get(media_item['baseUrl'] + "=w500-h250")

        test = Image.frombytes(mode="RGBA", size=image_size, data=image_data_response.content, decoder_name="raw")            
        result.append(test)

My error
No matter what i try i keep getting

ValueError: not enough image data

I even tried giving PIL the original size of the image it didn't help.

are you sure it is RGBA? Maybe it is only RGB? And maybe decoder is not raw but e.g. png (If it exists)

tried that mode doesn't appear to effect it.  the file is jpg btw.  I havent found any other options for decoder in the docs https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

usually I was using something like Image.open(io.Bytes(image_data_response.content), ...)

My hero this worked test = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data_response.content))  Go ahead and post an anwser.

In your own words, where the code says decoder_name="raw", and mode="RGBA", exactly what do you think these values mean, and how did you choose them? Given those settings, and the image dimensions, how many bytes of data do you think should be needed? (If you want to use tools like this, you should be able to answer such a question confidently first.) Did you try to find out how much data you actually get? Is it an appropriate amount? Did you try to look at the data? If you look at the data, can you recognize the format?

Usually I use something like
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data_response.content), ...)

Documentation for Image.frombytes:

Note that this function decodes pixel data only, not entire images.
If you have an entire image in a string, wrap it in a BytesIO object,
and use open() to load it.


If you plan to upload other files then you can also try to use io.BytesIO()
e.g. csv or excel to use with pandas
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file_data_response.content), ...)
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(file_data_response.content), ...)

Many modules allow to use file-like object instead of filename
and this allows to use io.BytesIO(data) or io.StringIO(data).
But sometimes there are exceptions.
e.g. OpenCV can't use cv2.imread(io.BytesIO(data)...)
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(file_data_response.conten, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

